# Subclass UIControl to make custom picker

Tags: ios, autolayout, uidatepicker, uicontrol

I am trying to make a custom picker control like `UIDatePicker`, but with a different data source to contain all the logic of the picker, and allow target-action behaviour.

To do this, I am subclassing `UIControl`, adding a `UIPickerView` and setting the picker view's datasource and delegate to the subclass. My problem is in the sizing of the views.

I've played around with `UIDatePicker` on every device, and it's default height is 216, and default width is 320. When stretching the width, the picker view doesn't stretch, but when stretching the heigh it does. To fit in with the system, I'd like my picker to be sized the same way.

I tried making a nib file for my subclass. I sized the view to 320x216, added a `UIPickerView` and hooked it up as an `IBOutlet`. In my implementation for `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` I set the the datasource and delegate of the picker, but when I run my test app I crash as the connected `UIPickerView` is still `nil` at that point.

My goal is to be able to use this using `init()` and in the storyboard like you can with `UIDatePicker`, so I ditched the nib and have been trying to get encapsulate everything in code. How can I set up the views to behave the same as the `UIDatePicker`?

Here is my current attempt (without using a nib since it all has to be in code to use in a storyboard):

```
class FWHeightPicker: UIControl {
    let pickerView: UIPickerView

    convenience init() {
        let size = CGSize(width: 320, height: 216)
        let origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        let frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)

        self.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: frame)

        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let size = CGSize(width: 320, height: 216)
        let origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        let frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)

        pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: frame)

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: pickerView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: pickerView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint])

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension FWHeightPicker: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
// Delegate/Datasource implementations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just should add your `pickerView` as subview to your `FWHeightPicker`. Then you should drop default AutoLayout constraints for your `pickerView` with `pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in favor of your desired constraints.

I've played a bit with your code (only removed extension for my convenience) - it's works fine and stretches/shrinks width and height of the picker to fit the size of view defined in your convenience init():

```
class FWHeightPicker: UIControl, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

  let pickerView: UIPickerView

  convenience init() {

    let size = CGSize(width: 320, height: 216)
    let origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    let frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)

    self.init(frame: frame)
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {

    pickerView = UIPickerView(frame: frame)

    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    pickerView = UIPickerView()

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
  }

  func commonInit() {

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self

    addSubview(pickerView)

    pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: pickerView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: pickerView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: pickerView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: pickerView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    self.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint])

  }

  // Delegate/Datasource implementations
  func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
  }

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return 10
  }

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return "row"
  }
}
```